# How can I uninstall VSCode on my Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall, visual-studio-code

I don't remember how I install it but I have tried to uninstall vscode by typing:

```
sudo apt-get purge code
```

and shows up the following line:

```
"Package 'code' is not installed, so not removed"
```

I cannot find the vscode in software center, so I can't uninstall it through the center. I've also tried:

```
umake ide visual-studio-code --remove
```

but it says it's not installed too.

The problem is, when I hit the win button and search `code`, the icon for code appears! And I can just run it fine, except that some extensions need reload(and after I reload the program, it still shows that need reload). If I install it and it appears that two icon for vscode will show up in the result of searching for "code" like the picture shows below.
[two icon show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbr60.jpg)

If I uninstall it after I install, it turn back to the former status, the icon still appear and the software work just fine.

Now I want to completely uninstall the vscode to get it clear. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

[VS code is typically installed](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) as a snap. Since it's clearly not installed using apt, you should be able to remove it with
`sudo snap remove vscode`

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I tried the snap way but it still shows that it's not installed.TAT